# Using metafor rma.mv to estimate correlation matrix with dependent effect sizes - significance tests (at least) are not credible in my results

Tags: meta-analysis

I am trying to run a meta-analysis that includes dependent effect sizes (correlations), nested into studies and then into measures, for which I ultimately want to estimate a mediation model. For that, I am trying to follow Wilson et al. (2016, https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jrsm.1199) who propose to collate a long dataframe of each correlation value with a factor that indicates which correlation it is testing, and then using that as a moderator.

However, the results differ from separate estimates of the correlation coefficients and, more importantly, the significance tests and confidence intervals appear far too liberal. I am not sure whether I misunderstand the method, the results, or both.

Where does the huge difference in significance values come from? What is a reliable way of estimating the correlations and their covariances for use in metaSEM?

```r
library(metafor)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading 'metafor' package (version 2.4-0). For an overview 
#> and introduction to the package please type: help(metafor).

dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~study, ~measure, ~pair, ~r, ~inv_N, 
  "UK_mediation", "affective", "pos_att", -0.38, 0.00446428571428571, 
  "UK_mediation", "cognitive", "pos_att", -0.2, 0.00446428571428571, 
  "UK_mediation", "affective", "neg_att", 0.18, 0.00446428571428571, 
  "UK_mediation", "cognitive", "neg_att", 0.21, 0.00446428571428571, 
  "DE_mediation", "only", "pos_att", -0.43, 0.000381970970206264, 
  "DE_mediation", "only", "neg_att", 0.26, 0.000381970970206264, 
  "longit", "T2_prej", "pos_att", -0.221742469419445, 0.004739336492891, 
  "longit", "T2_prej", "neg_att", 0.136975390214378, 0.004739336492891, 
  "longit", "T1_therm", "neg_att", 0.148356343157473, 0.004739336492891, 
  "longit", "T1_therm", "pos_att", -0.325301851215349, 0.004739336492891
)

#Approach per Wilson et al. - correlation pair as moderator
summary(rma.mv(r, 
               inv_N,
               random = ~ 1 | measure/study, 
               data = dat,
               method = "REML",
               mods = ~factor(pair)-1))
#> 
#> Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 10; method: REML)
#> 
#>   logLik  Deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc 
#>   2.9182   -5.8363    2.1637    2.4814   15.4970   
#> 
#> Variance Components:
#> 
#>             estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed         factor 
#> sigma^2.1  0.0000  0.0055      5     no        measure 
#> sigma^2.2  0.0000  0.0055      5     no  measure/study 
#> 
#> Test for Residual Heterogeneity:
#> QE(df = 8) = 25.1654, p-val = 0.0015
#> 
#> Test of Moderators (coefficients 1:2):
#> QM(df = 2) = 726.4284, p-val < .0001
#> 
#> Model Results:
#> 
#>                      estimate      se      zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
#> factor(pair)neg_att    0.2389  0.0179   13.3561  <.0001   0.2038   0.2739  *** 
#> factor(pair)pos_att   -0.3917  0.0179  -21.8970  <.0001  -0.4267  -0.3566  *** 
#> 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

#Basic approach for single correlation
summary(rma.mv(r, 
       inv_N,
       random = ~ 1 | measure/study,
       data = dat[dat$pair == "pos_att",],
       method = "REML"))
#> 
#> Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 5; method: REML)
#> 
#>   logLik  Deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc 
#>   3.4054   -6.8107   -0.8107   -2.6519   23.1893   
#> 
#> Variance Components:
#> 
#>             estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed         factor 
#> sigma^2.1  0.0040  0.0631      5     no        measure 
#> sigma^2.2  0.0040  0.0631      5     no  measure/study 
#> 
#> Test for Heterogeneity:
#> Q(df = 4) = 19.1211, p-val = 0.0007
#> 
#> Model Results:
#> 
#> estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub 
#>  -0.3224  0.0478  -6.7481  <.0001  -0.4160  -0.2287  *** 
#> 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I am no expert here so this is just a comment not an answer. I suspect that if you estimate one model on the whole dataset you are estimating common heterogeneity over the whole data-set and if you estimate on a subset your estimate will be different as it is based purely on that subset.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense to me and might well explain the small difference in the fixed effect estimate. However, I am more concerned about the significance level and confidence intervals, and am not sure that the drastic differences can be explained by that?

Comment: You could experiment with different values for the struct parameter like HCS to see if that helps. If you do not get a satisfactory answer here you could try the R mailing list for meta-analysis https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis//